# JMS pub/sub (using Camel) performance issue with MQ in XA transactions

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, xa

We have a java application doing JMS subscriptions that is using Camel as its JMS provider.

The application is subscribing to a topic using XA. It consumes 1 message in the queue, and then closes the XA transaction (each message is part of an XA transaction). Then the application re-attaches itself to the topic to start over the same process for each message.

When there are no messages to process, the client waits for 45 seconds (which is the XA transaction timeout) before closing the request and the XA transaction and starting a new iteration.

I have analyzed how this process is actually being done using a tcpdump, and here is what I found:

```
    MQ Client --[XA_START]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client <--[XA_START_REPLY]-- MQ Server

    MQ Client --[SPI (SUBSCRIBE)]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client <--[SPI REPLY]-- MQ Server

    MQ Client --[REQUEST_MSGS]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client --[REQUEST_MSGS]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client <--[NOTIFICATION]-- MQ Server

    MQ Client --[MQCLOSE]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client <--[MQCLOSE_REPLY]-- MQ Server

    MQ Client --[XA_END]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client <--[XA_END_REPLY]-- MQ Server

    MQ Client --[XA_COMMIT]--> MQ Server
    MQ Client <--[XA_COMMIT_REPLY]-- MQ Server
```

This is process is on a durable subscription, so each of the iterations (even when there is no message to consume) ends up generating I/O on the MQ server (I think, mostly on the SYSTEM.DURABLE.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE queue, where MQ keeps trace of its subscribers).

Having a somewhat high number of subscribers doing this process, the MQ server ends up I/O bound, with +4000 IOPS on the MQ logs disks (even outside of business hours, when there are no messages to consume). This process also consumes ~3 CPU outside of business hours.

I am a bit puzzled that using XA on pub/sub scales so bad, and I am wondering if there is any way to implement this solution without doing so much I/O.

Comment: If your were doing the same thing but reading from a queue does it perform better?  What version of IBM MQ is running on the server?   What version of IBM MQ jar files are you using with camel?

Comment: @JoshMc Yes, using a queue instead of pub/sub would perform much better as MQ wouldn't have to do I/O on each iteration. However, this is a pub/sub application, and it cannot be redesigned to use queues. Both MQ server and client are running on v7.5.0.7.

Comment: MQ v7,5 went out of support in April 2018.  Have you tested this with something newer?  v8.0 goes out of support April 2020, so that is not recommended, and v9.0 has not been announced but  my guess is April 2021, so I would suggest 9.1.0.3 since it has the longest life.  If your app does not change subscriptions (ex: always stays subscribed to the same topic string(s)), you can just administratively subscribe QUEUES to those topic strings and have apps read directly from the queues, this also means the publish side of things sees no difference.

Comment: @JoshMc Migrating to a more recent version of MQ is not an option currently, and I am really not sure that it would solve anything here...? I don't think that the other option you mentionned would be viable, since we sometimes have new subscribers popping up dynamically and also diseappearing.

Comment: Given that you are only consuming one message before closing the subscription, the REQUEST_MSGS part of the MQ client protocol will be doing you little good. Suggest turning off Read Ahead. Can you add a little information to your question about the need for XA - what is your other resource apart from MQ?

Comment: Does your logic allow for consumption of more than one message inside the XA-transactions ? Transactions really start to shine only once you batch multiple messages inside..

Comment: @MoragHughson The other resource is a database record that gets updated when the information from a message is retrieved.

Comment: @AxelPodehl It does not. 1 message + insert in a database = 1 transaction. The issue basically is that the subscribe operation is part of the XA transaction (i.e. for each transaction, the Camel framework does the subscribe operation over again).